# Wrong Python version returned, with correct $PATH set in ZSH

Tags: unix, path, zsh, osx-el-capitan, python3

something very wrong is happening with my environment set up. As I am trying to learn, I decided to reinstall Mac OSX El Capitan on my Macbook Pro and start installing and configuring stuff from scratch. Shell I am using is ZSH and I have configured it a bit with Oh-My-ZShell.

**My $PATH and Python:**

```
~ ❯ echo $PATH
/Users/edchigliak/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/edchigliak/bin
~ ❯ python --version
Python 2.7.10
~ ❯
```

Screenshot below clearly shows that there are two Python2's installed in `/usr/bin` and a Homebrewed Python3 in `/usr/local/bin`.

[image: Terminal screenshot of Python2 and Python3 paths]

**Here is the result of `printenv` (only entries related to PATH and SHELL):**

```
PATH=/Users/edchigliak/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/edchigliak/bin
PWD=/Users/edchigliak
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/zsh
SHLVL=2
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.lRGo5iu4NA/Listeners
TERM=screen-256color
ZSH=/Users/edchigliak/.oh-my-zsh
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

**First entry in my `.zshrc`**:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin
```

Many thanks!

Comment: None of these are called literally `python` which is the command you are typing in. What do you get with `type python`?

Comment: @tripleee Hey thx for the quick reply. I get this `python is /usr/bin/python`

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you think this result is "wrong".

Comment: I think it is wrong because I changed my `$PATH` in `.zshrc` file to `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin` and thought that `which python` should now return python 3xx

Comment: It should not; only `which python3.xx` could possibly return that result.

Answer (score 0):

Only binaries named exactly `python` will be considered when you type `python` at the shell prompt.

If you want `python` to execute `python3`, the simple way to accomplish that is to set a function or alias in your personal shell startup files.

You absolutely mustn't make `python` point to `python3` system-wide because this will break some OS and third-party tools which require `python` to be Python version 2. The two are mutually incompatible languages (or dialects, if you prefer).

To review what's happening here, when you type `command` at the prompt, the shell iterates through the directories in your `PATH` and looks for an executable file named exactly `command` in each, until it finds one, or runs out of places to look. It will simply ignore any files with other names, even if they would happen to be similar, like `xcommand` or `commandante` or `command3.xx`. If you have an alias or a function, that will be used instead, though your `PATH` will perhaps then be consulted to locate other commands called by your alias or function.

Comment: I understand this part, what I don't understand though is: why does `which python` return system one, even though I have changed the $PATH variable in my .zshrc file? ALso, why is the entry `PATH` in the output of the `printenv` set to this ridiculously long path instead of the one I set in .zshrc? Thanks!

Comment: Probably other parts of your `zsh` startup files amend the path with something like `PATH=$HOME/bin:PATH`. It should only be necessary once, of course. But this has no direct relevance here and isn't at all mentioned in your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The shell searches PATH for **exact matches**. When you type in `python`, it tries to find an executable matching `^python$`; `^python...$` is not the same.

In your case, it could be there is no python in /usr/local/bin or perhaps there's a permissions issue with it, which would make it be skipped.

1) If there is no `python` in `/usr/local/bin`:

You could use `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python` to create a soft link `python` pointing to the Python interpreter you want to use. Because /usr/local/bin is searched first for your PATH, the shell should now find this link.

2) If file exists in `/usr/local/bin` but doesn't have *execute* permission, try `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/python`.

Can't think of other problems right now.